# typechecking python NamedTuple in both python 2 and 3

Tags: python, mypy, namedtuple

I have a Python code that works with both python2 and python3 and uses mypy.
I managed to have my namedtuples typechecked with the following *really convoluted* method:

```
try:
    from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
except ImportError:
    TYPE_CHECKING = False

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import NamedTuple
    Foo = NamedTuple("Foo", [("foo", int)])
else:
    from collections import namedtuple
    Foo = namedtuple("Foo", ["foo"])

correct = Foo(foo= 1)
incorrect = Foo(foo= "bla") # error: Argument 1 to "Foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

Note: using something like this to define fields only once does not work:

```
foo_typed_fields = [("foo", int)]
foo_fields = [f[0] for f in foo_typed_fields]
```

Question: Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- install the official [typing module backport](https://pypi.org/project/typing/) for Python 2 (e.g. `pip install typing` or `pip2 install typing`), then just do the following:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

Foo = NamedTuple("Foo", [("foo", int)])
```